# ansible deploy to multi aws accounts using codebuild

Tags: ansible, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

The `ansible` playbook I'm running via `aws codebuild` only deploys to the same account. Instead of using a separate build for each account, I'd like to use only one build and manage multi-account deployment via `ansible inventory`. How can I set up the ansible static library to add yml files for every other aws account or environment it will be deploying to? That is, the inventory classifies those accounts into dev, stg & prod environments.

I know a bit about how this should be structured and that is to create a yml file in the inventory folder having the account name and also create a relevant file in the group-vars subfolder without the yml extension. But, I do not know the details of file contents. Can you please explain this to me?

On the other side, codebuild environment variable is given a few account names, the environment, and the role it should be assuming in those accounts to deploy. My question is how inventory structure and file content should be set up for this to work?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to act on resources in different account, the general idea in AWS is to **"assume"** a role in that account and run API calls as normal. I see that Ansible has a module '**sts_assume_role**' which helps to assume a role. I found the following blog article that may give you some pointers. Whether you run the ansible command on your laptop or CodeBuild, the idea is the same:

- http://www.drivenbydevops.io/aws-ansible-and-assumed-roles/

Comment: The link is helpful, thank you.
can someone help me with structuring the inventory folder and file contents which represent every separate account?